# Web page works in Visual Studio but not IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I have created a Registration page, in MVC, which is hosted on IIS 8. The page works perfectly in Visual Studio but once it is moved to IIS 8 it loses all it's functionality. When I browse the page it loads up with all the required fields but once the button is pressed the page seems to hang. Using Telerik Fiddler I can see the application opening but then I receive the following from Fiddler:

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
4   404 HTTP    website.url /Home/Registration  4,893   private text/html; charset=utf-8    chrome:14668
```

I have followed the thread with similar issues [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846924/site-works-in-visual-studio-test-but-not-iis-server-aspx) but I have checked all the permissions but so far nothing worked. The page directory is inside a website in IIS, inside a new directory. If anybody has any suggestions as to what I should change or how I should publish the solution it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What .NET frameworks are available on the server? Which server version are you using? What VS version? What ASP.NET Version?

Comment: @Webbanditten Well im Using IIS 8 application manager which has .Net v2.0, 2.0 classic, 4.5 and 4.5 calssic. I am also using Visual Studio 2012 with .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Comment: Seems fine - Is there any proxy in play? How are you deploying it?

Comment: @Webbanditten I would publish the application on to my local machine and then using Remote Desktop Connection I would connect to the computer which is hosting the site. Inside the wwwroot folder is the website and then inside the website folder is a folder with the application files in there. From the IIS 8 manager I can "Browse" the application which looks all good but the functionality doesn't seem to work.

Comment: "once the button is pressed the page seems to hang" sounds like the script files are not properly loaded in your page. Can you check that in Fiddler log? You must learn a little bit JavaScript debugging at browser side before moving on to IIS/ASP.NET side.

Comment: @LexLi Once I press the send button I still received the following message from Fiddler which shows a HTTP error 404.